# no me puedo conectar a otro dispositivo de LAN (socket python)

Tags: python, socket

Como dice el título, no me puedo conectar como servidor a ningún otro dispositivo que está en LAN. El error es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./servidor.py", line 8, in <module>
    sock.bind(('10.0.10.1', 8000))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Entiendo que el cliente no podrá darme una respuesta mientras no haya un script de cliente, pero aun así el servidor debiese conectar. Este es el codigo que utilizo:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('10.0.10.1', 8000))
sock.listen(5)

while True:
        conexion, addr = sock.accept()
        print 'Conexion establecida'
        print addr

        peticion = conexion.recv(1024)
        print peticion

        conexion.send('Mensaje enviado desde el servidor')
        conexion.close()
```

Utilizado como localhost funciona perfectamente.
De antemano, gracias !!

Comment: ¿Pero es '10.0.10.1' una ip del dispositivo donde ejecutas el server (host)? bind no conecta con un dispositivo remoto, bind asocia el socket a una ip/puerto local determinado (visible o no en la red local) ...

Comment: Así es, 10.0.10.1 corresponde al switch que tengo conectado a la PC y el switch va a un router. Intenté conectarle con la IP que le asigna el router al switch (192.168.0.xx) y nada... He intentado a otro PC que tengo al switch y nada...

Answer (score 0):

No entendí bien tu pregunta. Lo que voy a responder es sobre que ese script te da un error cuando lo ejecutas.

Revisa si esa es la ip de tu máquina, puedes revisar la ip de tu máquina en un sistema GNU/Linux con:

```
ip addr
```

o con

```
hostname -I
```

En el caso de windows puedes utilizar.

```
ipconfig
```

Por ejemplo, en mi caso, que uso WSL y tengo una LAN de clase C, es decir, inicia con 192, puedo ejecutar lo siguiente.

```
$ hostname -I | grep -Po '192.168.1.*? ' --color
192.168.1.67
```

Encuentras la verdadera ip y la pones en

```
sock.bind(('<la verdadera ip>', 8000))
```

Comment: Mi pregunta es, por qué no me puedo conectar a otros dispositivos de mi LAN... Tengo un router que usa direccionamiento clase C y le tengo conectado un switch en el que tengo 2 pc con direccionamiento clase A. El switch toma como 10.0.10.1 y 192.168.1.32, aun asi no me conecta y señala el mismo error 'socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address' . He intentado conectarlo a todos los dispositivos que tengo y nada....

Comment: Ese error surge porque es una dirección IP equivocada. ¿Ya intentaste correr el servidor en la con la dirección IP que te arrojaron esos comandos (depende del SO que tengas)?

Comment: Las direcciones IP no están equivocadas. He usado Nmap para verificar las direcciones de los dispositivos que quiero conectar.

Comment: nmap no sirve de nada para este caso, me refiero a la dirección IP el equipo donde la corres, es decir, de la máquina que va a ser el servidor. Ese código corre del lado del servidor con su propia dirección IP. Luego el cliente, con otro código, va a apuntar a la ip del servidor.

Comment: Entiendo @Cuauhtli , me ha quedado muy claro! muchas gracias.